# function getById Raphael js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, raphael

Secondly, I have an SVG form transform in different path using raphaeljs lib.
I would like to get a path by calling him with the function of raphaeljs 2.1.0 => getById(id);
However Chrome or Firefox tell me that there is no function getById ! I don't understand why ?

This is a piece of my code :

```
rsrGroups = [path_c_trsp,path_i_trsp,path_l_trsp,path_o_trsp];
len = rsrGroups.length;

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    var el = rsrGroups[i];

el.mouseover(function() {
    rsrGroupsMin.forEach(function(el){
        var getPath = el.getById('el.id'); // here is  the method called !
        alert(getPath);
        el.animate({opacity: 0.5},350,function () {});
        rsrGroups2.forEach(function(tri){
            tri.animate({opacity: 0.5},350,function () {});
        });
    });
    this.animate({opacity: 1},350,function () {});
});
}
```

And this is the error given by Chrome :

> Uncaught TypeError: Object Raphaël’s object has no method 'getById'

I tried different things but no one works :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getById is a method on the paper object, not the element i.e.

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
paper.getById('id')
```

or if you don't have access to the paper variable you could call el.paper.getById

Comment: Thank you, I find it by myself after looking at my code ^^
I have to do var getPath = **rsr**.getById(this.id);

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean `el.getElementById('el.id')`?